# SQL using a different approach then CASE statements

Tags: sql, case, alternate

[image]

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN symbol - 'D' THEN 'Domain'
        WHEN symbol LIKE 'A%' THEN 'Alpha'
        WHEN symbol = 'C' THEN 'Charlie'
    END
FROM
    table
```

I would like to avoid case statements, since its severely impacting query runtime. I have about 8 million records in the database, and evaluating each case statement is wreaking havoc on server memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (mysql, sql server, postgres, oracle, etc)? Is `CASE WHEN symbol - 'D'` intentional or a typo in the question? I can't help but think that the LIKE is the thing that is gobbling resources. 8M records isn't very large. Are there other processes competing for resources on your server? Lastly, I removed your `method` tag since that is unrelated to sql.

Comment: need performance metrics and explain plans to help understand if this is really the problem.  Function based indexes can pre-calculated and store the values can be used instead and dramatically can improve performance.  These get updated when values on which they are based change.  Also if you eliminate "NULL" symbol's is it better? since you now null can't be D, A or C. `Where symbol is not null` or do you need NULL values or are there no nulls...

Comment: A simple case expression on a column is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck, compared to the data retrieval, joins and filtering costs.

Comment: What else is your real query actually doing?  A basic CASE like this on a straight select from a single table with one column is not going to cause any problems

Answer (score 0):

You could create another table MAP (table name, column, value, match) and record all such cases. Initially check the table for a match (query MAP for symbol in you example) and if no match is found execute the CASE statement and insert the value in the MAP table.

This may not be a real performance improvement but you could export MAP to a data structure and use it in your SQL scripts. Or you could update the internal map data structure from MAP table. The internal map may grow as your data but I think this would improve the performance.